# What would keep my 2007 Pontiac Torrent from starting?

Tags: starting, pontiac, torrent

I have a 2007 Pontiac Torrent. Sometimes my car won't start. When I turn the ignition it will just click, but when I turn the wheel a little it will crank. Could it be the starter? I just got a new starter 10 months ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds more like a problem with the ignition switch, possibly some kind of interference with the steering wheel lock. Do you usually park on the street with your wheels turned? If so, maybe try to make sure your wheels are pointed straight before you shut off the car. This should take the binding out of the steering linkage and put less stress on the steering wheel lock.